# trouble with byobu custom status

Tags: ubuntu, bash-expansion, byobu

I'm trying to add nVidia GPU utilization to my byobu-tmux status line.  I've installed [gpustat](https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat) which returns

```
~$ gpustat
myhost                 Mon Aug 19 17:26:51 2019  410.48
[0] GeForce GTX 1080 Ti | 22'C,   0 % |     0 / 11178 MB |
[1] GeForce GTX 1080 Ti | 41'C,   0 % |     0 / 11175 MB |
```

then I wrote a text processor saved to ~/.byobu/bin/2_gpu as suggested in the byobu web page for custom status.

```
~$ cat .byobu/bin/2_gpu
#!/bin/sh
echo "$(gpustat | tail -n+1 | sed -nr "s/\[[0-9]\].+([0-9]+)\s\%.*$/\1%/p" | tr [:space:] ',' | head -c-1)"
```

from the bash shell that seems to work; whether the shebang is sh or bash doesn't seem to matter, it works fine:

```
~$ .byobu/bin/2_gpu
0%,0%
```

however I can't get that text onto the byobu-tmux status line. A simpler custom status works fine, but there's some problem escaping the quotes and/or '$' in the regex argument to the sed command.  I'm not sure why echo is even needed, but removing the `echo "$(...)"` doesn't help, nor does adding backslashes on the inner double-quote and '$' characters.

Answer (score 0):

okay, after an immense amount of fiddling, this seems to do what I want, with the bonus of nice color-coding:

```
#!/bin/sh
SED_PATTERN='s/^.*([0-9]+)\s%.*$/\1%%,/p'
GPUSTAT="$(gpustat | tail -n+2 | sed -nr $SED_PATTERN | head -c-2)"
echo "#[bg=blue]GPU:$GPUSTAT#[bg=black]"
```